First element if match a condition using *ngFor
I need to get the first element of the items$ when the subscribed flag in true. This is my code:
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; let first = first;"> </ng-container>
In this momement my first element can be also an item with subscribed flag false. What I need is to take the first item that have the subcribed flag true. Is is possibile with ngFor?

What about just creating a new observable and using this:
firstSubscribedItem$: Observable<any>;

// ...
this.firstSubscribedItem$ = this.items$.pipe(
    map(items => items.find(item => item.subscribed))
);

// in your html
<div *ngIf="firstSubscribedItem$ | async as firstSubscribedItem"></div>

